# g++: error: /usr/lib64/atlas/libsatlas.so: No such file or directory

Tags: software-installation, python, libraries

I am trying to compile this code https://thoth.inrialpes.fr/src/deepmatching/ which is supposed to be as simple as running the `make` command but am getting the error

> g++: error: /usr/lib64/atlas/libsatlas.so: No such file or directory

I read online that it is because I am missing the atlas library so have tried running the command `pip install atlas` yet am still getting the same error. Could I get some advice please on how I can fix this.

Comment: Please be more accurate. Are you sure about *lib**s**atlas*? What is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the software's `README.txt` file:

> This program has been built on a fedora18 x64 machine and tested on
> Mac OS X.  *No assistance* will be given to compile the code on
> other OS.

One way that appears to work (I've only tested it with `./deepmatching --help`) is:

- install the `libatlas-base-dev` package and its dependencies
- run

  ```
   make clean
   make LAPACKLDFLAGS="$(pkg-config --cflags --libs blas-atlas)"
  ```

**Note that this is almost certainly not the only way and quite possibly not the optimum way, since there is a multitude of different BLAS/LAPACK/ATLAS implementations available in Ubuntu**. See for example [What is the relation between BLAS, LAPACK and ATLAS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17858345/4440445)